# using query with not null, count, group and label

Tags: google-sheets

Here is my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PPFuFWbxWi9iIdtYBJvnSNB1j1cjjQutepF3hnpGoFM/edit#gid=478650644

Under reports I want to use Query to make a table that give the years and the count for the years.

The data is coming from a named range which is all the data under Auditions.

You can see where I've been working.

Under Reports A8 is showing a value that's not in the original data.

The same formula in Col C shows the correct data in C8. Not sure why.

I do have a nice table at E3 but there is a blank row. I read that this is because there are empty cells being included in the query and to use not null.

But using not null in E11 gives an error.

It seems so simple. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

`=QUERY(AuditionsTab, "select D where D is not null", 1)` - Returned an incorrect value in A8, copied over to Col C and then it return all correct values.

`=QUERY(AuditionsTab, "select D, count(A) group by D label count(A) '# of Auditions'",  1)` - works but there is a blank row at the top.

`=QUERY(AuditionsTab, "select D where A is not null, count(B) group by D",  1)` -  not working

Answer (score 0):

The `A8` value is correct, it is just not formatted appropriately (day 2,018 is July 10, 1905).

For E11 please try:

```
 =QUERY(AuditionsTab, "select D, count(A) where A is not null group by D",  1)
```

ie don't jumble up the `select` and the `where` clauses.